# Storing an integer and bit in a single word

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I was reading through a [presentation on the implementation of malloc](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/sp2012/lectures/09-malloc.pdf), and on slide 7 it suggests storing a regions size and availability in a single word to save space. The alternative is to use two words, which is wasteful as the availability bit only needs to be 0 or 1.

This is the given explanation:

- If blocks are aligned, low-order address bits are always 0
- Why store an always-0 bit?
- Use it as allocated/free flag! When reading size word, must mask out this bit

http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs241/sp2012/lectures/09-malloc.pdf

But I'm not really understanding how this works and how it could be implemented in C. Why is one bit of the size integer always 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - If blocks are aligned, low-order address bits are always 0

This is the key to understanding what it going on. Many CPUs require that multibyte primitive values be stored at addresses divisible by the number of bytes in the primitive: 16-bit primitives need to be stored at even addresses; 32-bit `int`s need to be stored at addresses divisible by four, and so on. An attempt to access an `int` through a pointer that corresponds to an odd address results in a bus error.

In systems like that `malloc` must always return an address suitable for storing any primitive supported by the given CPU. Therefore, if CPU supports 32-bit integers, all addresses returned by `malloc` must be divisible by `4`. Such addresses are said to be *aligned*. To comply, `malloc` implementations pad sizes blocks requested by the program by 0 to 3 bytes at the end to have length divisible by `4`. As a consequence of this decision, the last two bits of an address of an aligned block will always be zero. An implementation of `malloc` can use these bits for its own purposes, as long as they are "masked out" before returning the result to callers.

Answer (score 1):

[malloc(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) (as specified by Posix) should

- return a fresh block of memory; or `NULL` on failure; the returned pointer is not an alias of any other pointer in the program
- return a suitably aligned block of memory. Alignment constraints are compiler, ABI, and processor specific. (Often, the alignment should be two words).

The size is not always zero. (actually, it is never zero). You could round it up to a multiple of two words, and use the last bit as a used/free bit.

However, pointers returned by `malloc` should be suitably aligned, e.g. to 8 bytes. So their bottom 3 bits are zero, and the *allocated* size in bytes of the `malloc`-ed zone is a multiple of 8 bytes (above the requested size passed to `malloc`), so the last 3 bits are zero (and you could use the last bit for other purposes, e.g. a used/free bit).

Answer (score 1):

`Why is one bit of the size integer always 0?`

I see why this is confusing, but I don't think that's what they're saying on slide 7. They're saying that the low-order **address** bits are always 0.

Memory addresses of objects are aligned to specific boundaries, which means objects are aligned to a memory address that is a multiple of their size.

So a 64-bit integer is aligned to an eight-byte boundary; 
0x7fff315470d8

If a pointer is always aligned to an eight-byte boundary, then the low-order three bits are always zero. ie: 0x8<sub>16</sub> = 1000<sub>2</sub>

Basically, you can stick whatever you want in those low-order bits, so long as you take them out before dereferencing the pointer. In the 64-bit case you have 3 bits that are always 0, so you can store 3 "flags". In the case of this power point, they're saying take that lowest bit and use it for an "allocated" flag. Stick a 1 in it as long as the memory is allocated, mask it out when you send the pointer to the user.